# incomplete RSA decryption with large XML file type - JAVA

Tags: java, xml, security, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have a problem when decrypting XML type my file my returns incomplete data algorithm and rare symbols.

`public File decryptFile(File fileInput, X509Certificate certificate) throws BadPaddingException, Exception {
        try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileInput))) {
            byte[] encryptedKeyBytes = new byte[dis.readInt()];
            dis.readFully(encryptedKeyBytes);
            PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
            rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] rijndaelKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedKeyBytes);
            SecretKey rijndaelKey = new SecretKeySpec(rijndaelKeyBytes, "Rijndael");
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            dis.read(iv);
            IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);
            try (CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(dis, cipher)) {
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileInput.getAbsolutePath() + ".xml")) {
                    byte[] data = new byte[16];
                    int theByte;
                    while ((theByte = cis.read(data)) != -1) {
                        System.out.print(new String(data));
                        fos.write(data, 0, theByte);
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
        return new File(fileInput.getAbsolutePath() + ".xml");
    }`

this code returns me the data

```
</ctaAbonBenef><distPago>00000</distPago><item>00000</item><pagoPoder>N</p�|���[�[W�Z�5��Q�
```

I think this has to do with UTF-8, but I can not solve.

Now I can also believe that it is the encryption algorithm to use, I leave just in case.

`public static void generateFileEncrypt(File fileInput, PrivateKey privateKey, String folderSave) throws Exception {
        String fileOutput = folderSave + "\" + fileInput.getName() + ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_SUFFIX;
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));
        Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        KeyGenerator rijndaelKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Rijndael");
        rijndaelKeyGenerator.init(128);
        Key rijndaelKey = rijndaelKeyGenerator.generateKey();
        byte[] encodedKeyBytes = rsaCipher.doFinal(rijndaelKey.getEncoded());
        output.writeInt(encodedKeyBytes.length);
        output.write(encodedKeyBytes);
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        output.write(iv);
        IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rijndaelKey, spec);
        try (
                CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, symmetricCipher);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileInput)) {
            int theByte;
            byte[] data = new byte[16];
            while ((theByte = fis.read(data)) != -1) {
                System.out.print(new String(data));
                cos.write(data, 0, theByte);
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            cos.flush();
        }
    }`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I haven't digested all your code; I stopped when</strike> I saw you trying to decrypt with the public key, and encrypting with the private key. That's sort of like a digital signature, but your padding will be all wrong and you should use the `Signature` class if that is what your really want to do.

The public key is used to encrypt, or to verify a digital signature. Use the private key to decrypt, and see if that resolves your problem.

---

You are still doing it wrong. Don't call it "encryption" if the key isn't private.

But anyway, I think the printing to stdout looks wrong because you are converting the entire buffer to text. The last block is likely to be padded, so it won't decode to valid text—it's padding; it wasn't part of the input file, and you aren't writing it to the decrypted file, but you are printing it.

Change to encrypt with the public key, decrypt with the private key, and then change your printing to this:

```
System.out.print(new String(data, 0, theByte));
```

Even better would be to specify the character set of the data (probably UTF-8, since it's the default for XML).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is encrypt the file with the private key as you can see in the method generateFileEncrypt but decrypt the file with the public key, it returns me the data with odd symbols.

Comment: @rodrixd See my update. And stop wasting cycles on useless math.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should do the opposite. encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key..

Comment: An RSA keypair can encrypt in both directions.

Comment: @christopher Encryption provides confidentiality. If you use a public key, you don't have confidentiality, so it isn't "encryption," and it's not RSA. It's just a useless modular exponentiation.

Comment: But the problem here is that the software is incorrectly decrypting. Mathematically, this still should work. This is not relevant to the problem. I added this comment because If the answerer thought that encrypting with the private key is going to cause this, they would be wrong. If they didn't, then their answer shouldn't be an answer. Other than that, I agree with everything you said. There are use cases for encrypting with the private key though, for example for authentication.